# Implementing a protocol by delegating to existing functions

Tags: elixir

I'm learning Elixir by modeling a board game, and I have this code:

```
defprotocol Board do
  def can_handle_move(self)
  def handle_move(self, move)
end

defimpl Board, for: List do
  def can_handle_move(self), do: Enum.empty?(self)
  def handle_move(self, move), do: List.delete(self, move)
end
```

The implementation looks more complicated that it really is. Actually, `can_handle_move` is just `Enum.empty?` and `handle_move` is just `List.delete`. Does Elixir have a way of expressing this? Something like:

```
defimpl Board, for: List do
  def can_handle_move = &Enum.empty?/1
  def handle_move = &List.delete/2
end
```

...which doesn't compile. I've also tried without the `def`s.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `Kernel#defdelegate/2` for it.

```
defimpl Board, for: List do
  defdelegate can_handle_move(self), to: Enum, as: :empty?
  defdelegate handle_move(self, move), to: List, as: :delete
end
```