# Share functions across protocol implementations in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I am just working through Dave Thomas' book and am currently exploring Protocols in Elixir. I know I can fallback to a generic protocol implementation with `@fallback_to_any true`. For example:

```
defprotocol Caesar do
  @fallback_to_any true
  def encrypt(string, shift)
  def rot13(string)
end

defimpl Caesar, for: BitString do
  def encrypt(string, shift) do
    # implementation for binary
  end

  def rot13(string) do
    # implementation for binary
  end
end

defimpl Caesar, for: List do
  def encrypt(string, shift) do
    # implementation for character list
  end

  def rot13(string) do
    # implementation for character list
  end
end

defimpl Caesar, for: Any do
  def encrypt(string, shift) do
    # generic implementation
  end

  def rot13(string) do
    # generic implementation
  end
end
```

However in the above case, basically every implementation of `rot13/1` would look like this:

```
def rot13(string) do
  Caesar.encrypt(string, 13)
end
```

Still, I currently have to repeat this in every implementation, which seems utterly wrong. Is there a way to share `rot13/1` across all implementations of `Caesar`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So I found [this question about delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18219689/implementing-a-protocol-by-delegating-to-existing-functions) in implementations. It made me wonder whether `defdelegate` works inside protocols and indeed it does! So a possible solution to this is as follows:

```
defmodule Caesar.Shared do
  def rot13(string) do
    Caesar.encrypt(string, 13)
  end
end

defprotocol Caesar do
  def encrypt(string, shift)
  defdelegate rot13(string), to: Caesar.Shared
end

defimpl Caesar, for: BitString do
  def encrypt(string, shift) do
    # implementation for binary
  end
end

defimpl Caesar, for: List do
  def encrypt(string, shift) do
    # implementation for character list
  end
end
```

I'm still interested in other answers. Maybe there is still a better, more idiomatic way to do this directly inside the protocol definition.

Comment: Your solution is definitely the way to go!

Comment: @JoséValim thanks! I'm not sure about the module name `Caesar.Shared` though. Is there a naming convention for this, or is it yet to be established?

Comment: In a lot of places the named convention is Utils but I wouldn't worry about it. As the project grows, you will likely find a good place/name to host such related functions together.

Comment: As of now (master branch for elixir 1.13), this solution does not work anymore.
As stated in https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/11347#issuecomment-951359916, support for defdelegate inside a protocol was only incidental, and it was removed

Comment: @epilgrim thanks for taking the time to comment here! Do you happen to know a better way of doing this?